# Can't figure out where SQL Syntax error is coming from

Tags: mysql, sql

**Question** 
I'm writing a basic SQL script to create two tables and their columns. When I try to run the script I'm getting a Syntax error. Could you please let me know why this syntax error is occurring and how to fix it? I couldn't understand why it was happening. Maybe I've missed something out or it's a simple error.

**Error Displayed**
[image: Error Given]

**SQL Code**

```
CREATE TABLE customer (

ID INTEGER,
Firstname VARCHAR (15),
Lastname VARCHAR (15),
Address VARCHAR (254),
Postcode VARCHAR (8),
Email VARCHAR (254),
Phoneno INTEGER,
Points INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE purchases (

ID INTEGER,
GameName VARCHAR(30),
ConsoleType VARCHAR (20),
Price VARCHAR (254),
PaymentType VARCHAR (20),
Date TIMESTAMP,
PointsGained INTEGER
)
```

Comment: You missed the `;` between the two statements

Comment: Phoneno integer?  PaymentYype varchar?  You're going to have other problems.

Comment: Really, I copied your command and executed it created tables without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using mysql, i guess integer type is int, not integer

```
CREATE TABLE customer (

ID INT(11),
Firstname VARCHAR (15),
Lastname VARCHAR (15),
Address VARCHAR (254),
Postcode VARCHAR (8),
Email VARCHAR (254),
Phoneno INT(11),
Points INT(11)
);

CREATE TABLE purchases (

ID INT(11),
GameName VARCHAR(30),
ConsoleType VARCHAR (20),
Price VARCHAR (254),
PaymentType VARCHAR (20),
Date TIMESTAMP,
PointsGained INT(11)
);
```